# why is my maskMoney plugin not working?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple input text.

```
<input type="text" name="" id="amountInput"/>
```

this is my javascript.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#amountInput').maskMoney();

App.init();
});
```

my script is link correctly because I did a console log. I'm using Jquery 2.1.4 and i tried with 1.9 and i still don't get any results. I was wondering if there is something I'm missing.

Comment: is there any errors in console????

Comment: Is there any error in console? Also check App.init(); works fine

Comment: i get no error on my console, and App.init(); works fine when i remove it my app doesn't start.

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle or codepen to show the issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed to include  `jquery-maskmoney.js` (https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney) you need to include this too.